# How does a database implementor migrate their database engine to a new data structure?

Tags: architecture, database, project-management, workflows

I am working on implementing a database of sorts and am stuck wanting to make it *perfect* from the get go because I realize I don't know how to *migrate* the database engine from one data structure to another (as the data structure implementations evolve). I am afraid that if I pick a database data structure, then I won't be able to adjust it down the road.

Take for example a hash table for sake of this question. Say I implemented a database using a hash table, and I used hashing algorithm `h1()`. Well that literally distributes my records all over the place. Now I want to use hashing algorithm `h2()`. I can't just boot up my database with this new hash algorithm, it won't know how to read the locations of the existing database records. So I need to somehow migrate one hash to the other. I don't see how to do that. Not only that, *but then I need to do this for every client that upgrades to v2 of my database* so to speak. Only when you start the new one or something.

My question is, how do database implementors generally manage this problem? How do they effectively migrate their database implementation? Take for example migrating from a hash-table to a b+tree, or b+tree-1 to b+tree-2. How do they serialize the old data into the new form in practice? How do they get everyone off of the old data structures and onto the new ones?

Comment: How did you solve the surprise h2 problem when you made the first data structure? Seems like the same problem.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet haha.

Comment: In most cases applications/servers in this situation find it necessary to support _both_ - or even _all_ - prior formats online and may also provide offline copy-and-transform tools because transitioning users is, in practice, extremely difficult if not actually impossible.  In many cases you're fortunate that most of your users transition even given several _years_ notice of future non-support of their format.  It causes a large amount of complexity and pain in moving forward, not least of which ensuring, via design and _testing_, that the old stuff you're no longer interested in still works.

Comment: Will knowing how database implementors generally solve this problem, help you solve your specific problem, though? The simplest method is to require the data to be exported from the old version of the DB software, then re-imported offline in the new version. Consider if this might be sufficient for your situation, because if it is, it's undoubtedly the easiest to implement and will let you get beyond being "stuck" on this point.

Comment: I don't believe there *is* a way how "database implementors generally manage this problem". Even in the single company I work for, one R&D team has the approach that they support at least three major releases or at least ten years (whichever is longer), and accept any data in either the current format or any other format within that timeframe and transparently update it to the latest version. Another R&D team has completely changed the data format twice in the last 3.5 years and does smaller tweaks every couple of months, and simply expects the user to recreate the data from scratch ever time.

Comment: A good book: https://databaserefactoring.com/

Comment: This problem is in no way special to databases or their implementations. The problem almost always arises when persistence is a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are dealing with is a change in the structure of the files that are used to persist information.

There are two main ways to deal with this:

1. Perform a conversion from the old format to the new format during installation of the software version that relies on the new format. The conversion tool would be able to recognize and read files stored in the old format and write them back in the new format. Where a change in data structures is involved, that typically means reading the data in in the old data structure, copying it to the new data structure and writing that out again.

   This method only works if during installation it is known which files are used by the software.
2. Maintain (read-only) support for old formats and convert them when needed. The conversion is now built into the application itself.

The important part in both cases is that either the conversion tool or the application itself can recognize the different file formats and switch to the correct implementation for reading them in.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you have a new database/data structure that works and supports all that the old one supports… What follows is the solution that comes to mind.

Make an interface/façade/abstraction layer for what the software uses from the database/data structure. Then make three implementations: one uses the old one, one uses the new one, one tries to use the other two implementations.

The third implementation will use the new implementation first. It will try to read from the new one first, if it didn't find anything, it will read from the old one. And it will write to the new one only.

If that works, you can add the code to always write to the new database when you read from the old one. If that works, you can add the code to remove form the old one what is in the new one. If that works you can make an task that access all the data, so it gets moved to the new database.

Finally, you could either package that to do the migration online or offline. For the online version, you would add code to stop using the old database (do not initialize the first implementation at all) when it is empty, even delete it if that is supported. For the offline version, you would have it run as part of an update installer.